# Aside tag out of article tag?

Tags: html

I think I understand the usefulness of aside tag but I do not understand why it only works with its context.

Let me explain, imagine a page with an article in the main column and a content block concerning the article in a sidebar.

Logically I should use aside tag to link this content block to the article tag but aside is only linked by its context. This block should be into the article tag in the code.

Is there a way to link those two HTML5 sections?

Thanks

Comment: Why should you use `<aside>` for the element in sidebar?

Comment: Because my content bloc will be linked with my page, not with my article. It seems to me that aside is directly related to its context.

Comment: No. `<aside>` should be used to provide information that does not directly relate to its surrounding context.

Comment: I don't understand the same thing.
In the Spec : "The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content."
On html5doctor.com : http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/